# Difference between jQuery Deferred then and always

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

some time ago I found myself in troubles when working with jQuery promises. I tried to execute code after an array of promises was solved by using the .then() function. However, it did never work when one of the promises was rejected. (With always() function works)

If I look at the official documentation I find this:

```
Then: Description: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object
      is resolved, rejected, or still in progress.

Always: Description: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred
        object is either resolved or rejected.
```

Apparently, on both cases when my promises are solved/rejected it should execute the callback functions of then and always, but it doesnt.

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3uczyhj0/)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 it should execute the callback functions of then and always, but it doesnt.
```

No function is attached to handle rejected promise at first example. Add `.fail()`, `.always()` chained to `.then()` or include second parameter at `.then()` to handle rejected promise `rjct.reject()`

```js
var rslv = $.Deferred();
var rjct = $.Deferred();

var promises = [];
promises.push( rslv );
promises.push( rjct );

$.when.apply( null, promises ).then( function( res ) {
    alert( "not finished" );
}
// handle rejected promise
, function( reason ) {
    alert( "handle " + reason );
});
rslv.resolve("123");
rjct.reject("rejected promise");

var rslv2 = $.Deferred();
var rjct2 = $.Deferred();

var promises2 = [];
promises2.push( rslv2 );
promises2.push( rjct2 );

$.when.apply( null, promises ).always( function( res ) {
    alert( "finished" );
} );
rslv2.resolve();
rjct2.resolve();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```